# How to get count(*) total from DB2 with having clause?

Tags: db2, db2-400

How do I get the sum of all return rows with group by clause in DB2?

For example:

Desc     Ctr
----     ---
Bowl      30
Plate     21
Spoon      6
Sum       57

SELECT COUNT (name) as Desc, Count(*) OVER ALL
GROUP BY name

Above query return error from DB2.  What is the proper SQL statement to return SUM of all rows?

Thanks,
Brandon.

Comment: how does your table look like and what is your expected output? can't understand from your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query,
 select name, count(*) from table group by name

Comment: Count(*) will provide the same count as count(name) in each row...  I want to see total number of rows which would be 57.

Answer (score 0):

What is your platform of Db2?

If you want just the total count of rows, then

```
select count(*)
from mytable
```

If you want the subtotals by name plus the total, SQL didn't originally support that.  You had to union the two results.

```
select name, count(*) as cnt
from mytable
group by name
UNION ALL
select '', count(*)
from mytable
```

However more modern versions have added `ROLLUP` (and `CUBE`) functionality...

```
select name, count(*) as cnt
from mytable
group by name with rollup
```

**Edit**
To put a value for name, you could simply use `COALESCE()` assuming name won't ever be null except in the total row.

```
select coalesce(name,'-Total-') as name, count(*) as cnt
from mytable
group by name with rollup
```

The more correct method is to use the `GROUPING()` function
either return just the flag

```
select name, count(*) as cnt, grouping(name) as IS_TOTAL
from mytable
group by name with rollup
```

or use it to set the text

```
select case grouping(name) 
         when 1 then '-Total-'
         else name
       end as name
       , count(*) as cnt
from mytable
group by name with rollup
```

**Inculde total**

To include the total on each line, you could do something like so...

```
with tot as (select count(*) as cnt from mytable)
select name
       , count(*) as name_cnt
       , tot.cnt as total_cnt
from mytable 
     cross join tot
group by name
```

Note that this will read mytable twice, once for the total and again for the detail rows.  But it's real obvious what you're doing.

Another option would be something like so

```
with allrows as (
   select name, count(*) as cnt, grouping(name) as IS_TOTAL
     from mytable
    group by name with rollup
)
select dtl.name, dtl.cnt, tot.cnt
from allrows dtl
     join allrows tot
        on tot.is_total = 1
where
  dtl.is_total = 0
```

Comment: Hi Charles, 
Thanks for your recommendation.  The DB2 is on AS400 platform and it supports rollup function.  

Rollup works and I am almost there.  

The result is below.  Is there a way to change the NULL on the last row to a meaningful name so that my application can refer to it?  

Code Count Rollup
30      6     6
50    61    61
81    19    19
NULL  86    86

Comment: Hi Charles, requirement has changed.  Now, I need to include the total count on every row.  column1 would have the count of the individual state.  Column2 would have the total count of all states.  For example:  
SELECT COUNT(A.state), Count(*) as 'total' FROM TABLE A
WHERE A.date = '12/5/2017'
GROUP BY A.state  How can I include the total in column2 for each row?  Sorry, I am learning DB2 SQL programming. Hope you can shed some light to this!  Thanks again.

Comment: @Brandon168 see the include total section